# Is there a way to list cross project service accounts in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

we have 600+ projects which were created manually, I want to get list of cross project service accounts in those projects,
gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=myproject
command just showing all the service accounts, and I believe some service accounts has permissions in several projects.I have checked gcloud alpha and gcloud beta, seems like there is no such functionality.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: To confirm, by "cross-project service accounts", I think you mean Service Accounts owned by one project (foo) but added to the IAM policy of another project (bar), correct?

Comment: yes correct that's what I meant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this!

You want to use an account that has sufficient access (all the projects and their IAM policies).

Enumerate all the projects. For each project enumerate its IAM policy. Identify Service Accounts (`members:serviceAccount`) that have an email address of the form `{anything}@{project}.iam.gserviceaacount.com`. List the values of `{project}` for this project.

Because of the inherent complexity, I think this would benefit from being written in a language other than the shell. But, for convenience, here's a (hacky) Bash script:

```bash
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  printf "\nProject: ${PROJECT}"
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
  --flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
  --filter="bindings.members:serviceAccount*" \
  --format="value(bindings.members)" \
  | grep -E -o "[a-z][-a-z0-9]{4,28}[a-z0-9]@[a-z][-a-z0-9]{4,28}[a-z0-9].iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
  | grep -E -wv "service-[0-9]{12}@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{4,28}[a-z0-9].iam.gserviceaccount.com"   \
  | grep -E -wv "@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
done
```

This:

1. Get the policy of each accessible (!) project
2. Flattens the results to filter by `serviceAccount`'s
3. Outputs only the (Service Account) members
4. Filters (`grep`) by those that are `{foo}@{bar}.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
5. Filters (`grep`) by those that aren't Google-managed (`service-[0-9]{14}`)
6. Filters (`grep`) by those that aren't owned by the current project

> **NOTE** `[a-z][-a-z0-9]{4,28}[a-z0-9]` matches Google Project and Service Account IDs (I think!)

The result includes Google-managed accounts (`*.iam.gserviceaccount.com`). One way to exclude these would be to **only** include Service Accounts that have one of your projects in the domain (`{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com`).

Comment: DazWilkin thank you so much! this helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pleased to hear that it helped. I added another `grep` line to exclude the Google-managed service accounts. If you remove the `printf` line, you can pipe the results through `| sort | uniq` to get a list of unique service account emails.